# NDSolve's output ignores multiple valid solutions

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, physics, nonlinear

I'm looking for solutions to a boundary problem involving a non-linear Hamiltonian
$$
H(q,p) = \frac{1}{4}\left(q^{2}+p^{2}\right)^{2},
$$
whose solutions are oscillatory but have a complex time dependence. I'm interested in all possible solutions $\left(q(t),p(t)\right)$ that satisfy the following boundary conditions:

$$\begin{cases}
q(0)&=-1 \\
q(\pi)&=1
\end{cases}$$

and I am absolutely sure there are a lot (maybe an infinity) of them. When I ask *Mathematica* to solve the boundary problem

```
NDSolve[{q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), 
  p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), q[0] == -1, q[Pi] == 1}, q[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

I get only one solution, which looks like

[image]

and satisfies the boundary problem. What I can't figure out is that, manually, I found another solution:

```
 NDSolve[{q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), 
   p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), q[0] == -1, p[0] == 1.200859}, 
  q[t], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

whose graph is

[image] .

How can I manipulate `NDSolve` such that it displays more solutions? Since they may be infinite, not all can be displayed, but why is *Mathematica* just choosing a particular solution in a set of infinite ones?

Comment: Have you seen ["SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveSPRK.html)?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Man... I've never heard of that, and it's awesome. If you send me one more piece of info I'll be happy to cite you on the paper I'm working at ;)

Comment: Very glad to help. :)

Comment: I was just reminded that there is a bug in SPRK (I ran into it). I posted a fix: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90066/symplecticpartitionedrungekutta-shows-strange-error/91398#91398

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

You seem correct QuantumBrick that the `Shooting` method is better:

```
sols = Map[First[
     NDSolve[{q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), 
       p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2),
       q[0] == -1, q[Pi] == 1}, {q, p}, {t, 0, Pi},
      Method ->  "BoundaryValues" -> {"Shooting", 
       "StartingInitialConditions" -> {p[0] == #}}]] &, Range[0.25, 2, 0.25]];

Plot[Evaluate[q[t] /. sols], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

---

Introducing small error into the starting conditions to find other approximate answers (which is similar to your manual answer)

```
sol = Table[
   NDSolve[{q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), 
     p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2),
     q[0] == -RandomReal[{0.99, 1.01}], 
     q[Pi] == RandomReal[{0.99, 1.01}]}, q, {t, 0, Pi}], {10}];

Plot[Table[q[t] /. sol[[i]], {i, 1, 10}], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thansk for the answer, but I sort of solved it right this moment using the Shooting method with starting conditions on the momenta. Is your method more precise then this one?

Comment: @QuantumBrick The Shooting method may be better ...

Comment: "I sort of solved it right this moment" - next time, @Quantum Brick, consider posting an answer to your own question if you manage to figure out a solution after asking it. :)

Comment: @J.M. Should I just delete my answer?

Comment: @Young, please don't, as you've written it already. I was just suggesting to the OP that answering your own question is kosher here, should s/he be in that situation the next time.

Comment: I was going to suggest answering my own question, but Young already edited his answer and I agree with it pretty much.

Comment: Using negative values for p[0], for instance `-Range[0.25, 2, 0.25]`, gives additional solutions.

Answer (score 9):

The ode can be solved symbolically, except `DSolve` runs into trouble with the branches of `Sqrt[]` and we end up with a general solution that is essentially `-Abs[solution]`.  As result, `DSolve[]` can't solve the boundary conditions (they cannot be satisfied since the computed `q` is nonpositive for all initial conditions).  But all is not lost.

```
ode = {q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2)};
bcs = {q[0] == -1(*,q[Pi] == 1*)}; (* change to half an IVP *)
dsols = DSolve[{ode, bcs}, {p, q}, t];
(* DSolve/Solve warnings about inverse function being used *)
```

`DSolve` returns two solutions (with the integration constant **`C[2]`**). We can, it turns out if we check, transform one of the solutions into a differentiable solution. Here we define the solution as a pair of functions `qfn` and `pfn` and check that they solve the ode.

```
With[{sol = Last@dsols},              (* the Last leads to a solution *)
 {qfn = Evaluate[PowerExpand@Simplify[q[t] /. sol] /. t -> #] &,
  pfn = Evaluate[PowerExpand@Simplify[p[t] /. sol] /. t -> #] &}]
With[{sol = First@dsols},             (* the First does not lead to a solution *)
  {qfn2 = Evaluate[PowerExpand@Simplify[q[t] /. sol] /. t -> #] &,
   pfn2 = Evaluate[PowerExpand@Simplify[p[t] /. sol] /. t -> #] &}];
(*
  {-Cos[C[2] + #1 + #1 Tan[C[2]]^2] Sec[C[2]] &, 
   Sec[C[2]] Sin[C[2] + #1 + #1 Tan[C[2]]^2] &}
*)

ode /. {q -> qfn, p -> pfn} // Simplify
ode /. {q -> qfn2, p -> pfn2} // Simplify  (* does not satisfy ode *)
(*
  {True, True}

  {Sec[C[2]] Sin[t + C[2] + t Tan[C[2]]^2] == 0, 
   Cos[t + C[2] + t Tan[C[2]]^2] Sec[C[2]] == 0}
*)
```

We cannot solve the boundary condition `q[Pi] == 1` symbolically, but `NSolve[]` can handle it, if we restrict the domain.  First, let's look at what we're going to solve:

```
eq = q[Pi] - 1 /. Last@dsols // Simplify // PowerExpand;

Plot[eq /. C[2] -> c2, {c2, 0, 1.4}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`NSolve` won't be able to solve the equation in a neighborhood of `Pi/2`, since there are infinitely many solutions.  It also has trouble with the solution `C[2] -> 0` for some reason.

Here we compute 1001 solutions:

```
bcsols = Join[
   {{C[2] -> 0}},
   NSolve[{eq == 0, 0 < C[2] < Pi/2 - 0.01}, C[2]]
   ];
Length@bcsols
(*  1001  *)
```

Here's a look at the first twenty:

```
Plot[Take[qfn[t] /. bcsols, 20] // Evaluate, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here's a check of the boundary conditions of the 1001-st solution:

```
qfn /@ {0, Pi} /. bcsols[[1001]]
(*  {-1, 1.}  *)
```

This will get you another 9,999 solutions on the other side of `C[2] == 0`:

```
bcsols2 = NSolve[{eq == 0, -Pi/2 + 0.01 < C[2] < -0.01}, C[2]];
Length@bcsols2
(*  9999  *)
```

Not `NSolve` is a bit finicky: The constraint `C[2] < 0` is not good enough; you need `C[2]` less than a (not too small) negative number.

Comment: This is way more than what I've asked. I'll study your answer in a few moments, but thank you very much for the insights you provided. This is an exceptional answer.

Comment: @QuantumBrick You're welcome...& thanks!

Comment: @QuantumBrick Actually you seemed to hint that you were looking for "a lot (maybe an infinity) of them" -- ha-ha :)

Comment: (For some reason I can't tag you) - Physics told me there should be an infinity of them, but the algebraic approach you performed was quite unexpected and welcome ;)

Comment: @QuantumBrick Authors of posts are automatically tagged without the @ stuff. From a quick math glance, too, one expects infinitely many.

Comment: This Hamiltonian is rather important in Physics and appears quite often in the field of quantum optics. It described properties of what we call a "Kerr medium" in quantum electrodynamics. I love Mathematics and practically only work with it, but those names Physics provides are quite sonorous to the ear, ain't they? ;)

Comment: Your final plot shows solutions only for `p[0] >= 0`.  I believe that solutions for `p[0] < 0` also exist.

Comment: @bbgodfrey They're in `bcsols2`.

Answer (score 6):

An alternative, perhaps simpler, approach makes use of the fact that the Hamiltonian is a constant of the motion here.  This can be validated by constructing the time-derivative of the Hamiltonian.

```
eqs = {q'[t] == p[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2), p'[t] == -q[t] (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2)};
q[t] eqs[[1, 2]] + p[t] eqs[[2, 2]]
(* 0 *)
```

Setting the Hamiltonian equal to `ω^2` then yields

```
eqs1 = eqs /. (p[t]^2 + q[t]^2) -> ω
(* {Derivative[1][q][t] == ω p[t], Derivative[1][p][t] == -ω q[t]} *)
```

which `DSolve` handles without difficulty.

```
s = Collect[DSolve[{eqs1, q[0] == -1, q[Pi] == 1}, {p[t], q[t]}, t], 
    {Sin[t ω], Cos[t ω]}, Simplify] // Flatten
(* {p[t] -> Cos[t ω] Cot[(π ω)/2] + Sin[t ω], q[t] -> -Cos[t ω] + Cot[(π ω)/2] Sin[t ω]} *)
```

Edit: Finally, `ω` is determined by `p[t]^2 + q[t]^2 == ω`

```
Total[#^2 & /@ ({p[t], q[t]} /. s)] // FullSimplify
(* Csc[(π ω)/2]^2 *)
```

So, the eigenvalue equation is

```
ω Sin[(π ω)/2]^2 - 1 == 0
```

Plotting this function indicates the locations of the roots,

```
Plot[ω Sin[(π ω)/2]^2 - 1, {ω, 0, 12}]
```

[image]

And the roots themselves are given by

```
freq = ω /. NSolve[ω Sin[(π ω)/2]^2 - 1 == 0 && .4 < ω < 20, ω]
(* {1., 1.33333, 2.44206, 3.64927, 4.31956, 5.72552, 6.26172, 7.76635, 
    8.22672, 9.79293, 10.2027, 11.812, 12.185, 13.8267, 14.1712, 15.8383, 
    16.16, 17.8479, 18.1508, 19.8559} *)

p1 = Plot[Evaluate[q[t] /. s /. ω -> freq[[1 ;; 6]]], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

The derivation above misses some solutions.  Apply `DSolve` to `eqs1` without the boundary conditions.

```
{q[t], p[t]} /. DSolve[{eqs1}, {p[t], q[t]}, t] // First
(* {C[2] Cos[t ω] + C[1] Sin[t ω], C[1] Cos[t ω] - C[2] Sin[t ω]} *)
```

The first boundary condition yields

```
% /. t -> 0
(* {C[2], C[1]} *)
```

Consequently, `C[2] == -1` and `ω == 1 + C[1]^2`.  The second boundary condition then yields

```
Reduce[(%%[[1]] /. {C[2] -> -1, t -> Pi}) == 1, C[1]] // FullSimplify
(* (Sin[π ω] == 0 && Cos[π ω] == -1) || (Sin[π ω] != 0 && C[1] == Cot[(π ω)/2]) *)
```

The second result is the one obtained earlier.  The first, however, is new.  It is satisfied by `ω` any odd integer.  Corresponding solutions are, for instance,

```
p2 = Plot[Evaluate[{-Cos[t ω] + Sqrt[ω - 1] Sin[t ω], -Cos[t ω] - Sqrt[ω - 1] Sin[t ω]} /. 
    ω -> {3, 5}], {t, 0, Pi}, PlotStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

Between them, plots `p1` and `p2` depict all solutions for `ω < 6`.

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

Incidentally, one might have expected `DSolve` with the boundary conditions and

```
SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
```

to return both sets of solutions but it does not.

Comment: I'm really curious about why DSolve couldn't map the second solution. I think this might be a good question on its own.

Comment: I also believe some other solutions are missing. You chose $C[1]=\sqrt{\omega-1}$, but $C[1]=-\sqrt{\omega-1}$ should also be a solution.

Comment: @QuantumBrick    `p2` shows curves for `{-Cos[t ω] + Sqrt[ω - 1] Sin[t ω], -Cos[t ω] - Sqrt[ω - 1] Sin[t ω]}`.  The first expression in the list evaluates the positive square root, and the second expression the negative square root.

Comment: @QuantumBrick  With respect to your first comment, the second solution is, in essence, the solution of a Sturm-Liouville problem.  The related function, `DEigensystem` cannot treat inhomogeneous boundary conditions, and it seems likely that `DSolve` cannot either.  Certainly, all Sturm-Liouville problems in the `DSolve` documentation have homogeneous boundary conditions.  If you were to ask this as a new question, the likely answer would be that Wolfram, Inc has not yet implemented this capability.