# trivial solution in NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

I want to find b[x] and c[x] in the interval 0

```
b'[x] - d[x] = 0,
c[x] - e[x] = 0,
lambda* d'[x] + b[x] (theta - k c[x]/(s+c[x])) = 0,
e'[x]-c[x]b[x]/(s+c[x]) = 0,
```

which b'[x] is first derivative of b[x] respect to x and constants of equations are:

```
lambda=0.2;k=2;s=0.5;theta=1;
```

and boundary conditions are:

```
c[1]=1, e[0]=0, d[0]=0, d[1]=0
```

The code I used is:

```
lambda=0.2;k=2;s=0.5;theta=1;

sol=NDSolve[{D[b[x],x] -d[x]==0,D[c[x],x] -e[x]==0,lambda*D[d[x],x]      
+b[x] (theta - k c[x]/(s+c[x]))==0,
 D[e[x],x] -c[x]b[x]/(s+c[x])==0,
c[1]==1,e[0] == 0,d[0]==0,d[1]==0},{b,c,d,e}, {x, 0, 1}]

p1=Plot[b[x] /. sol,{x, 0, 1},PlotStyle ->Red]
p2=Plot[c[x] /. sol,{x, 0, 1}]
```

but it returns just trivial solution:

```
c[x]=1, b[x]=0
```

What can I do to get nontrivial solutions of these equations? Could anyone help me? And one more question, I need answers which are in the interval 
`0<c[x]<1` and `0<b[x]<1`. How can I consider these in solving equations?

Answer (score 5):

`Shooting` method:

```
lambda=1/5;
k=2;
s=1/2;
theta=1;

sols = Map[First[
     NDSolve[{
       D[b[x],x] -d[x]==0,D[c[x],x] -e[x]==0,
       lambda D[d[x],x]+b[x] (theta - k c[x]/(s+c[x]))==0,
       D[e[x],x] -c[x]b[x]/(s+c[x])==0,
       c[1]==1,e[0] == 0,d[0]==0,d[1]==0},{b,c,d,e}, {x, 0, 0.5},
        Method ->  "BoundaryValues" ->
         {"Shooting",  "StartingInitialConditions" -> {c[0] == #}}]] &, Range[0,0.2, 0.1]];


Plot[Evaluate[c[x]/.sols],{x,0,1},PlotRange->All]
Plot[Evaluate[b[x]/.sols],{x,0,1},PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

Reference:

[NDSolve's output ignores multiple valid solutions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121929/ndsolves-output-ignores-multiple-valid-solutions/121933#121933)

Comment: Could you please let me know what is Range[-5, 0, 1] in your code? And also I have another question: Is there any way to get answers for b[x] and c[x] which are positive in all interval 0<x<1?

Comment: `Range[-5,0,1]` is the list`{-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0}` for starting values of `b[0]`

Comment: Does the first graph  show 3 different answers for c? Does your code show all the answers available for c[x] and b[x]?

Comment: So changing the range to another range would change the solutions, right?Actually I know that answers are in the interval  0<b[x]<1 and  0<c[x]<1. So should I change the range regarding to these information?

Comment: It doesn't show all the answers ... changing the range could reveal more "solutions"

Comment: I changed the Range to Range[0, 1, 0.2], but below errors appeared: is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. and some other errors. Would you help me more please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43620/discussion-between-sara-nj-and-young).