# How to Consider knowledge about solutions interval in ndsolve

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I want to find b[x] and c[x] in the interval `0<x<1`. Equations to be solved are 4 coupled equations as below

```
b'[x] - d[x] = 0,
c'[x] - e[x] = 0,
lambda* d'[x] + b[x] (theta - k c[x]/(s+c[x])) = 0,
e'[x]-c[x]b[x]/(s+c[x]) = 0,
```

which b'[x] is first derivative of b[x] respect to x and constants of equations are:

```
lambda=0.2;k=2;s=0.5;theta=1;
```

and boundary conditions are:

```
c[1]=1, e[0]=0, d[0]=0, d[1]=0
```

The code I use is as below (referencing to first answer in [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123383/trivial-solution-in-ndsolve/123384#123384)):

```
lambda=1/5;
k=2;
s=1/2;
theta=1;
sols = Map[First[
NDSolve[{
D[b[x],x] -d[x]==0,D[c[x],x] -e[x]==0,
lambda D[d[x],x]+b[x] (theta - k c[x]/(s+c[x]))==0,
D[e[x],x] -c[x]b[x]/(s+c[x])==0,
c[1]==0,e[0] == 0,d[0]==0,d[1]==0},{b,c,d,e}, {x, 0, 0.5},
Method ->"BoundaryValues" -> 
{"Shooting","StartingInitialConditions" ->{c[0] == #}}]] &, Range[0,0.5, 0.1]];
Plot[Evaluate[c[x]/.sols],{x,0,1},PlotRange->All]
Plot[Evaluate[b[x]/.sols],{x,0,1},PlotRange->All]
```

but when I change parameters of problem, for some parameters, value of c[x] and b[x] become negative.
I need answers which are in the interval 
`0<c[x]<1` and `0<b[x]<1`. How can I consider these in my code?

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Consider using `ParametricNDSolve` with its parameters given by those parameters in your equations that you are free to change.  You can then experiment easily with values for those parameters to see which values give solutions in the ranges you wish.  Indeed, it may be possible to automate that process.  Note, however, that some choices of parameters may well not give solutions in the desired range, and it may not be possible to do anything about this.  Please provide more information to help your readers provide more concrete responses.